# ng-selected not working in anagular.js 1.6.6

Tags: angularjs, forms, ng-options, angularjs-select

After a lot of tries and several hours :-(, I need some help:

I'm doing an update for a object in the database.

I'm doing an update for a object in the database all is working except setting the default value in a select.

First try:

```
 <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : departmentForm.codBoss.$invalid && !departmentForm.codBoss.$pristine }">
 <label translate="bosscode"></label>
 <select ng-model="vm.codBoss" class="form-control" required>
     <option value="">&nbsp;{{ 'selectBoss' | translate }}</option>
     <option ng-repeat="item in vm.chooseBoss" ng-
     selected="item.codUser==vm.codBossSelected" value="{{item.codUser}}"ng-selected ="item.codUser == vm.selectedUser">
     {{item.name}}, {{item.surname}}, {{item.codUser}}
     </option>
 </select>
 <p ng-show="departmentForm.codBoss.$invalid && !departmentForm.codBoss.$pristine" class="help-block" translate="fieldrequired"></p>
```

Here the ng-selected is not working... ng-selected is not working. I've checked the typeof and both of them are string.
The values for item.codUser are: MM, SM, CM.
And try with ng-selected = "item.codUser =='MM'" neither works.

After read here some posts, I've tried to use ng-options:

```
    <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : departmentForm.codBoss.$invalid && !departmentForm.codBoss.$pristine }">
                <label translate="bosscode"></label>
                <select name="codBoss" ng-model="vm.codBoss" class="form-control"
                ng-options="item.name + ' ' + item.surname + ' ,(' + item.codUser + ')' for item in vm.chooseBoss track by item.codUser"
                ng-init="item.codUser == 'MM'">
                <option value="">&nbsp;{{ 'selectBoss' | translate }}</option>
                </select>
               <p ng-show="departmentForm.codBoss.$invalid && !departmentForm.codBoss.$pristine" class="help-block" translate="fieldrequired"></p>
                <br/>
```

Here I've tried with ng-init or ng-selected.

What am I doing wrong?. All works perfectly with both options except the default selection... I need this becasue in a update all fields all filled with the actual data.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Don't use [`nSelected` together with `ngModel`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected#overview). Also don't use [`ngInit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit). Use [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) as `ng-options="item.codUser as (item.name + ' ' + item.surname + ' ,(' + item.codUser + ')') for item in vm.chooseBoss track by item.codUser"` and make sure sure a proper model value set in `vm.codBoss` that exists in the option list.

Comment: This does not work:       vm.codBoss = data.data.name + ' ' + data.data.surname + ' ,(' + data.data.codUser + ')' neither   vm.codBoss = {
                name: data.data.name,
                surname: data.data.surname,
                codUser: data.data.codUser
            };

Comment: This does not work:       `vm.codBoss = data.data.name + ' ' + data.data.surname + ' ,(' + data.data.codUser + ')' ` neither   `vm.codBoss = {
                name: data.data.name,
                surname: data.data.surname,
                codUser: data.data.codUser
            };`